# How to specify an Entity Framework connection string in WAWS configuration file?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

I am publishing a web app to Azure. I am developing in VS2013 using Entity Framework 6.0.

I am trying to specify my database connection string in the WAWS.json file, instead of in my web.config file, so that I can change the value at deploy time, rather than build time. (I am deploying my web app via a build job in Visual Studio Online.)

When I run my app, I get this error when trying to access the database;

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal 
(EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
```

I realize now that the Entity Framework connection string is quite a bit more involved than a typical connection string. VS2013 generated this for me in my Web.config:

```
<add name="EventPusherConfigurationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EventPusherConfigurationModel.csdl|res://*/EventPusherConfigurationModel.ssdl|res://*/EventPusherConfigurationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXXX;user id=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have no idea how to specify the equivalent in WAWS, or if it is even possible. This is what I have, but it doesn't work. It gets the error described above.

```
            {
            "connectionStringName": "EventPusherConfigurationEntities",
            "serverName":  "XXXXXXX",
            "databaseName": "XXXXXXX",
            "user": "XXXXXXX",
            "password": "XXXXXXX",
            "edition": "",
            "size": "",
            "collation": ""
        }
```

Is there a way to specify the Entity Framework connection string in the WAWS file so that it will work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it through portal:

Ibiza version (preview)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

Old Portal

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the links. Unfortunately, I have to do this without requiring manual changes in the portal. This is for an automated build/deploy job.

Comment: @MikeTaverne So, it seems that the connection string that your vs2013 generated is wrong. Try to connect to your DB using Sql Management Studio and it probably will fail. Search for your DB in portal and take the connection string from that. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/